# Cannot run scala in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-scala

I'm struggling with running Scala Hello World project using IntelliJ IDEA Scala plugin. The project is created without any problems but when I create function which should be run, the run button doesn't appear. I've got no idea why it doesn't work.

Version of IntelliJ - 2020.3.1 (Community Edition)
Version of Scala plugin 2020.3.18

1. [I've created Scala/sbt project (I'd also tried Scala/IDEA)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iccV1.png)
2. [Vanilla options (but I'd also tried other versions of JDK, Scala and sbt)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3W59.png)
3. [The run button is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNKXX.png)

My code is:

```
class Hello extends App {
  println("Hello world")
}
```

I've tried creating Scala worksheet and It works.

Comment: In Scala 2.13 you don't need to extend `App`. And try to convert the class to an object.

Answer (score 4):

When you extend `App`, it needs to be as `object Main extends App`, not `class Main extends App`.

See [Scala 2.13 specification 9.5](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/09-top-level-definitions.html) (emphasis mine):

> A *program* is **a top-level object** that has a member method *main* of type `(Array[String])Unit`

> The main method of a program can be directly defined in the object, or it can be inherited. The scala library defines a special class scala.App whose body acts as a main method

Answer (score 0):

As [Suma mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65523754/2359227), you should use object, and not class. The code of the `Hello` file should be:

```scala
object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello world")
  }
}
```

As stated in [YOUR FIRST LINES OF SCALA](https://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/your-first-lines-of-scala.html#the-hello-world-program). Please note that if you prefer to extend `App`, all of the statements will be executed, as stated in the last link:

> The argument of the scala command has to be a top-level object. If that object extends trait scala.App, then all statements contained in that object will be executed; otherwise you have to add a method main which will act as the entry point of your program.

Which means you have another option:

```scala
object Hello extends App {
  println("Hello world")
}
```

I have created a [gif that shows an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlE8N.jpg).